# Show $\mathbb{Z}_n^∗$ is an abelian group where $\mathbb{Z}_n^*=\{1 \le a \le (n-1)\mid \gcd(a,n) = 1\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I need to show that $\mathbb{Z}_n^∗$ is an abelian group where $\mathbb{Z}_n^*=\{1 \le a \le (n-1)\mid \gcd(a,n) = 1\}$.

I have tried specific examples for this such as $\mathbb{Z}_8$ and closure, identity, inverse, and associativity hold. But I do not know how to show this for any $n$.

I know that the Identity for any $n$ will be $1$ but I do not know how to show closure, inverse, and associativity.

Comment: So what did you try for $\mathbb Z_8^*$?  Did you determine the elements of $\mathbb Z_8^*?$

Comment: Hint: The order of $\mathbb Z_8^*$ is $4$.  If you know the additive group, $\mathbb Z_8^+ = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, which of these elements $a \in \mathbb Z_8^+$ are such that $\gcd(a, 8) = 1$?

Comment: I pretty much tried every combination of it. The set was {1,3,5,7} so multiplication modn for this set holds since you get a member within the set meaning closure holds. The identity would be 1(the only obvious thing). Inverse was 1(mod8) using the identity.

Comment: Note that if $n$ is prime then you do have a finite field and only the zero is not in . $\mathbb Z_n^*$. The elements considered in $\mathbb Z_n^*$ are the invertible  elements which are not divisors of $0$, What remains is known.

Comment: The formula given for Z in sloppy, inaccurate.  1 is not an element of that Z.  The closet [1] is an element  of that finite group.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$ then the group of units $R^{\times}$ is always abelian. Here we have $R=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $$R^{\times}=U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}=\Bbb Z_n^{\times}.$$ One can check that the units form a group and that one obtaines your group as the group of units from the commutative ring $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

The converse of the above need not be true. There are non-commutative rings with an abelian group of units: [Noncommutative rings with abelian group of units](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363242/noncommutative-rings-with-abelian-group-of-units/2363266), e.g., the polynomial ring $K[X,Y]$ over a field $K$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- First define the group law in this  set (starting point: multiplication in $\mathbf Z$).
- For the inverse, use  a Bézout's relation $\;ua+vn=1$ and translate it modulo $n$.
- Associativity should be deduced from associativity of multiplication in $\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 0):

**Well-defined:** Suppose $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$. Then $n\mid a-b$, *i.e.,* $a-b=kn$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. So $a=kn+b$. Hence $\gcd(a, n)=\gcd(b, n)$.

**Closure:** Let $[g]_n, [h]_n\in\Bbb Z_n^*$. Then $\gcd(g, n)=1=\gcd(h,n)$. Thus $\gcd(gh, n)=1$. (*Hint:* Use Bézout's Identity.)

**Associativity:** This follows from that of $\Bbb Z$ under multiplication.

**Identity:** The identity is $[1]_n$. Since multiplication is well-defined, it suffices to show that $[1\times g]_n=[g]_n$, which is quite clear to see.

**Inverse:** Suppose $[g]_n\in\Bbb Z_n^*$. Then, by Bézout's Identity, there exist $x, y\in \Bbb Z$ such that $xg+yn=1$; that is, $xg=1-yn$; so $[x]_n[g]_n=[1]_n$. Thus $[g]_n^{-1}=[x]_n$.

**Commutativity:** This follows from commutativity of $\Bbb Z$ under multiplication.

Hence $\Bbb Z_n^*$ is an abelian group.

Comment: One can find the same proof, pretty much, on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Answer (score 0):

You mean eqivalence classes modulo $n$, not integers themselves. The identity element is $1+Z_n$Abelianness and associativity are inherited from the integers.Note that if $a \equiv b \mod n$ then
 $$\gcd(a,n)=1 $$  iff  $$\gcd(b,n)=1$$ so it is legitimate to write $$\gcd((a+Z_n),n)=1$$. If $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $gcd(\alpha,n)=1$, then, by the uniqueness of prime decomposition,$ gcd(a\alpha,n)=1 $, which shows that the set of equivalence classes $\{a+Z_n|\gcd(a,n)=1 \} $ is stable under multiplication.Suppose that $\gcd(a,n)=1, 1 \le a \le n-1$. Then there exist integers $u$ and $v$ such that
$$ua+vn=1$$ Then $\gcd(u,n)=1$. Let $$U \equiv u \mod n, 1 \le U \le n-1$$ Thus
$$u+Z_n=U+Z_n$$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a+Z_n$